# Use Login Robox using username only like on reward sites

Tags: roblox

Hi i know this is probably not the place to ask this but i m stumped at the moment as i cant seem to find any reference or docs relating to working with Roblox. I mean sure they have an auth route etc but nothing detailed. I want to login user using username and give them roblox based on different actions they take on the site like completing surveys etc. Can anyone please give me links to some resources that would come in handy for the particular purpose. Thank you.

Comment: How would there be any security if only a username was required?

Comment: Roblox does not currently support any kind of OAuth or external login. The only way to authenticate a user is to use their undocumented login APIs which require both a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Roblox does not support any OAuth systems, but you still can use HttpService:GetAsync() function to get strings/data from web site(if the page in website display that text), the way to keep data that you recieved from url(web page) safe is to store script with HttpService:GetAsync() function in server side(example: RobloxScriptService). You need to allow http requests in your GameSettings -> Security in roblox studio. Script example:

```
  local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")

local stringg = HttpService:GetAsync("https://pastebin.com/raw/k7S6Ln9R")

print(string)
--Should outpud data written ot the web page, you can use any web page to store data even your own
```

The only two things that left is to make your web server rewrite the page, or just use some databases at your web site by placing their url into loadstring() function.
Now you just need to parse the string given by url to use it's data.
The pastebin url that i wrote into loadstring() just an example, you can write whatever you wan, but again you need to parse the data that you got from url, or just convert the string into type of text like on the page, and then just check is they written at url/webpage. Example:

```
local writtenpass = game.Players["anyplayer"].PlayerGui.TestGui.Frame.PasswordTextBox.text

local writtenlogin = game.Players["anyplayer"].PlayerGui.TestGui.Frame.LoginTextBox.text


local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")

local   response = HttpService:GetAsync("https://pastebin.com/raw/k7S6Ln9R")



local istrue = string.find(response, "{ login = ".. writtenlogin .." pass = ".. writtenpass .." }")

print(istrue)


if istrue == 1 then
        print("exist!")
--whatewer actions if login and pass exist
        end
```

You can wiew the page here https://pastebin.com/raw/k7S6Ln9R

Well that a lot of damage!
If it helps mark me